# Display remaining items count in a list of divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a horizontal list of divs, and I want to display the remaining items count while scrolling.

Here's a playground code i try on

```css
.horizontal {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.item {
  background-color: #f00;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.count {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff8a;
  width: 50px;
  left: 160px;
  height: 85px;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal">
  <div class="item"> A </div>
  <div class="item"> B </div>
  <div class="item"> C </div>
  <div class="item"> D </div>
  <div class="item"> E </div>
  <div class="item"> F </div>
  <div class="item"> G </div>
  <div class="item"> H </div>
  <div class="item"> I </div>
  <div class="count"> Count </>
</div>
```

So, How can i replace the count word with the actual remaining count?

Comment: Is abit unclear what you mean by *remaining*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this - you may want to add 6 for the border on both sides of the divs

```js
const count = document.querySelector(".count");
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".item").length;
document.querySelector(".horizontal").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  count.textContent = divs - parseInt(this.scrollLeft / 50)
})
```

```css
.horizontal {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.item {
  background-color: #f00;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.count {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff8a;
  width: 50px;
  left: 160px;
  height: 85px;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal">
  <div class="item"> A </div>
  <div class="item"> B </div>
  <div class="item"> C </div>
  <div class="item"> D </div>
  <div class="item"> E </div>
  <div class="item"> F </div>
  <div class="item"> G </div>
  <div class="item"> H </div>
  <div class="item"> I </div>
  <div class="count"> Count </div>
</div>
```